# What's the best way to extend classes in php 5.2.17?

Tags: php

In PHP 5.3 you can quite easily write say...

```
class Controller extends \Special\Controller
```

Currently I am having to work with php 5.2.17, how do you properly extend classes with this version?  I know there aren't any namespaces so I'm curious is it even possible to do this with a version <5.3

Comment: Just make sure you don't have any naming conflicts and it should work just the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class A
{
    //...
}

class B extends A
{
    //...
}
```

Namespaces don't change the behaviour of extension, as far as I know... the only difference is that your classes are all in one namespace (the global one) and they can't have the same name.

Comment: The common style pre 5.3: `\Special\Controller` would be `Special_Controller`

Comment: do I need to use a require_once so it's aware of the other class file?

Comment: The class being extended needs to be in-scope at the time of declaration, whether you do it by inclusion or autoloading is up to you.